# JS error while trying to perform filter actions in ext js grid

Tags: extjs3

I'm getting follwing error while I'm trying to filter data for the second time in ext js grid,I`m using IE8 and extjs 3,

```
error is->
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 27 Mar 2012 06:22:19 UTC


Message: 'this.dom.className' is null or not an object
Line: 7
Char: 49902
Code: 0
```

URI: http:ext/ext-all.js...any idea fellas???

Comment: I got the actual of problem of this,when store is empty and if we try to reload it like->store.reload(),this is the error it`s throwing,this is one condition and i`m sure there`s compatibility problem also.I tried the same in another computer it worked.

Comment: Now I want some suggestions like, when the store is empty how can I reload the grid???

Comment: Any other suggestions other than reload would be great,but I`m not supposed to destroy grid than load again...plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can fix this by reinstalling JDK.

Comment: ira.sagi87,I`ll definitly try this.Thanks for replying.